# Microsoft bot framework session timeout after user inactivity

Tags: c#, object, botframework, objectdisposedexception

I'm working on a scenario where the user is warned after 1 minute of inactivity and after another, 1-minute chat will auto close.

Callback is successfully invoked after 1 minute but when I'm using turnContext to send a message to user then it shows an exception that "cannot access a disposed object"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNkhr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Rol.png)

can we prevent to dispose object for some time or if there is any other solution so please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can't prevent the object

here you can find how to implement expire conversation [Automatically Expire Conversation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XilATvloOZ0&t=5s) & download the Nuget package [Automatically Expire Conversation](https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/BotTutorialSample/tree/master/BotComposer/28-SessionAgent)